# Conversion guideline

Tags: c++, type-conversion

What is the standard solution if you have two classes A and B, and you need to define conversions from A -> B and B -> A?

1. make A have a constructor taking B and A having conversion operator
   to B?
2. make both A and B have constructors from the other one?
3. make both A and B have conversion operators to the other one?
4. Some kind of a CPO `convert<To>(From)`
5. any other way???

(note 2 and 3 require circular dependency)

Comment: I guess depends on the situation... do you have any concrete example?

Comment: I do not believe there is any standard here. 1 - 4 will all work. My personal preference is to make this sort of a conversion explicit via methods instead of constructors. This can be `A::toB()`, or the `convert<To>(From)` which was your (4). But, this is a matter of preference and I have also used `ctors` in the past for this sort of a use-case.

Comment: There are too many factors that are important to any answer which are not presented here. Which classes do you have control over, if any? Is one of the classes considered more fundamental than the other (the relationship between `string_view` and `string`, for example)? And so forth. Without a specific case, there's no way to provide a viable answer.

Comment: I though it would be clear from points 2 and 3 that I have control over both A and B. Neither A nor B is more fundamental, they are on the same level. I did not include an example because I was asking for a general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked around the cppslack and there seems to be no standard/general case, so it boils down to the situation.

> (1) is what you do when you're extending an API, i.e. A knows about B
>   but B doesn't know about A;
>
> (2) or (3) is what you do when A and B are defined as part of the same
>   API, i.e. they know about each other;
>
> (4) is how you unify two unrelated APIs, i.e. neither A nor B knows
>   about the other.